# Intelij AppCode - String constants refactor : how can i extract multiple "hard coded" strings to a single strings file (like in android)

Tags: refactoring, constants, automated-refactoring, appcode

I want to extract multiple "hard coded" strings to a single strings file, is there a smart way to do it in AppCode?

I tried to find it, but the only solution for now is:

Let's say, I have file MyFile with string in it called time="7:30"

1. Extract each string with **refactor -> extract -> constant**
   It will be now in the header file of MyFile.
2. Move the constant manually from MyFile.h to my Constants file.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement here right now is to use **Move** refactoring instead of manual moving. There is no bulk inspection/refactoring for such use right now in AppCode.